# Probability regarding a contracting sequence of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The aim of the exercice is to prove that if $A_1, A_2, ...$ is a contracting sequence of events, that is : $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset ...$ then, $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ...) = lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n)$

a Hint which has been given to us was to apply De Morgan's law in order to get to the solution, so here I started : $$\Omega \backslash (A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ...) = (\Omega \backslash A_1) \cup (\Omega \backslash A_2) \cup ...$$
Then, I've applied the definition of a probability measure :
$$ P(\Omega \backslash (A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ...)) = P(\Omega \backslash A_1) + P(\Omega \backslash A_2) +... = \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(\Omega \backslash A_i)$$

At this point I don't know what's missing to conclude to the equality with the limit, I understand intuitively that here, as our sequence is contracting, we'll "converge" to what we're looking for but I don't know what I may be allowed to introduce here to get to the proof or if it's explicit enough here to conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $n$, $A_1\cap A_2...\cap A_n=A_n$ Therefore $P(A_1\cap A_2...\cap A_n)=P(A_n)$  The limits are then equal.

Comment: Well thank you very much! That hint they gave made me more confused instead of being simpler